# angular, how to combine modules

Tags: angularjs, electron, angular-module, angular-factory

I have a page **html1.html** with the module **mod1**

```
[html1.html]
<html lang="en" ng-app="mod1">
...
<script src="scripts/services/Data.js"></script>
```

And **Data.js** is a factory for **mod1**

```
[Data.js]
angular.module('mod1').factory('Data',[function(){
...
}]);
```

Then I have the same with a second page **html2.html** with the module **mod2**, and there I also want to use the same factory than before

```
[html2.html]
<html lang="en" ng-app="mod2">
...
<script src="scripts/services/Data.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/Train.js"></script>
```

**Train.js** is a factory for **mod2**, and then to combine **mod1** and **mod2** I do the following

```
[Train.js]
var mod2 = angular.module('mod2',[angular.module('mod1')]);
mod2.factory('Train',[function(){
...
}]);
```

But angular doesn't find the module **mod1**. What am I missing?

*Both **html1.html** and **html2.html** are renderers from the same Electron main application

Comment: Wait. where is the `mod1` module defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module dependencies are specified by name, so in `Train.js`

```
angular.module('mod2', ['mod1'])
```

You just need to include the file that defines `mod1`, ie the file that has

```
angular.module('mod1', ['maybe', 'some', 'deps', 'here'])
```

You include that file  in `html2.html` as well as any other files with providers (like `Data.js`) and everything in that module will be available.

Presumably you already defined the module `mod1` in `Data.js` or another file. Defining it again as you were in `Train.js` overrides the registered name with a new, empty one.